# Can I conclude that JavaMail doesn't work with GMail accounts?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail

I've been on this issues for days. I visited the forums, and I have tried different tweaks, yet no solution.

Please can some tell me why my sample javaMail code can't send a mail from any gmail account? Both for SSL and TLS.

Below are my code snippets;

```
public class EmailUtility {

    public static String USERNAME = "???@gmail.com";
    public static String PASSWORD = "???";
    public static String HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
    public static String PORT = "587";

    public static void sendEmail(String toAddress,
            String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST );
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT );
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME , PASSWORD );
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USERNAME ));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(toAddress)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(message);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Did you enable SMPT in GMail?

Comment: Did you discover the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail)?  If you read everything there and still can't get it to work, post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).